# Curses interface has blank spaces under GNU Screen and ssh

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, ncurses

I'm trying to run an application `sbopkg` that uses a curses interface in an ssh session running under GNU Screen (Tmux also has the same behavior). If I run `ssh` directly from the terminal emulator (either iTerm2 or Terminal on OS X), then I don't see any blank spaces.

Why am I seeing these blank spaces? Is there a way to configure `screen` or `ssh` to avoid this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a terminal description that says that the terminal supports back color erase (**`bce`**), but it does not actually do this.

GNU screen is configurable (`defbce` for instance), but apparently tmux is not (see for instance *[Support background color erase (bce) [was: Vim copy & paste trailing space issue] #109](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/109)*)

Further reading:

- [My terminal shows some uncolored spaces](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#bce_mismatches)

Comment: adding `defbce on` to my `.screenrc` fixed the issue.