# Losing color when starting screen session

Tags: linux, terminal, gnu-screen, colors

I have a RHEL 6.9 host that loses its color when starting a screen session. Vim colors and directory colors exist before starting the screen session. Here are a few settings to help troubleshoot:

- $TERM returns screen
- I am using `force_color_prompt=yes` in my bashrc
- `echo "$(tput setaf 1)red$(tput sgr0)"` successfully prints out red (in red)

Any advice on how to fix is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you try `screen-16color`?

Comment: How do I use that? Do I run it as a screen command or put it in .screenrc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `$TERM` returns `screen`

You've told the programs that you are running under Screen to look at [the `screen` entry](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-screen) from the terminfo database when they want to do terminal-related stuff like colourize output.  That entry tells them (via [the common `ecma+color` entry](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-ecma_color)) that the terminal has 3-bit standard colour support from 1976.

In fact, your version of Screen can very likely support a lot more than that.

You are probably looking for [the `screen-256color` entry](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-screen-256color), which tells them that the terminal supports 8-bit indexed colour, or even [the `screen-256color-bce` entry](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-screen-256color-bce) which specifies 8-bit indexed colour capability and *background colour erase* capability.

You tell them this by simple dint of setting the `TERM` environment variable to the value `screen-256color`, or `screen-256color-bce`.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/441899/5132

Comment: screen honors the 256-color escapes in either case (checked an hour ago).

Comment: It would, as its actual processing of SGR sequences is unaffected by the environment variable in some other process.  The version of Screen that wouldn't support more than that would be one dating from before the introduction (into Screen) of 8-bit indexed colour support.  I haven't checked when that was, because (as I said) it isn't the very likely case.  (-:

Comment: In either case, the explanation of why there's **no** color appears to be missing.

Comment: I tried `screen defbce/bce on` however the exec defbce or bce does not exist on the host. Also setting the TERM variable to one of the ones you suggested in and out of the screen session did not fix the issue.

Comment: I think there is some kind of limitation on this host. When I login to an ubuntu host start a screen session there and then have each terminal login to the problem host things work fine, I suppose because I am using  the settings of the original host.

Answer (score 0):

1. Place this in your `~/.screenrc`, create and add if not exists

   ```shell
   shell -$SHELL
   ```
2. Place this in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`, whichever shell you have configured.

   ```shell
   export TERM=screen-256color
   ```
3. Apply the changes

   ```shell
   source ~/.zshrc
   screen -S screen_name
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands in screen session:

```
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias l.='ls -d .* --color=auto'
alias ll='ls -l --color=auto'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias which='alias | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --show-dot --show-tilde'
```